# Rating plugin pass value to AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, rating

I'm trying to get value to two hidden fields in AJAX which somehow is not happening. I am using http://www.wbotelhos.com/raty/ rating plugin .

The value is not getting in AJAX

```html
<head>
   <title></title>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.raty.min.js"></script>

</head>
<?php
$id=1;
$msg_id=192;
?>
<body>
    <div id="click<?php echo $msg_id ;?>" onclick="rate('$id','$msg_id')">
        <input type="hidden" id="uniqueRateID" name="uniqueRateID" value="<?php echo                  $id; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="ratedJS" value="<?php echo $msg_id ;?>" />
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#click<?php echo $msg_id ;?>').raty({

    });

    function rate(a,b,c)
    {
        alert(a+'jkij'+b+'dfdf'+c+'dddd');
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 )
            { 
                var accdata=xmlhttp.responseText;
            alert(accdata);
                document.getElementById('request').value="Request Sent";
            document.getElementById('request').disabled=true;
            }
        }
       xmlhttp.open("GET","modules/manage friends/update_friend.php?ab="+a+"&&bc="+b+"&&             cd="+c,true);
       xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well looks like i   solve the problem , m posting it for future help

```
          <head>
   <title></title>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.raty.min.js"></script>

        </head>
       <?php

     $id=1;
          $msg_id=192;
               ?>
          <body>
              <div class="rate" id="rate" >
            <div id="click" name="click<?php echo $msg_id ;?>" >
   <input type="text" id="valrate" name="valrate" value="fff"/>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="uniqueRateID" name="uniqueRateID" value="<?php                         echo $id; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" id="type_id" name="type_id" value="<?php echo $msg_id ;?>" />
    </div>
       <script type="text/javascript">
              $('#click').raty({

                 });


         $("#rate").click(function()
          {
          var a = $('#uniqueRateID').val();
       var b = $('#type_id').val();
         var c = $('#valrate').val();


       $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "greet.php",
         data: "dataString=" + dataString,
         success: function(result){
             $("#response").html(result);
          }
       });   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using pure javascript to make the ajax request. To be sure you must encode the values send in get: encodeUricomponent(a)...

But as you are includeing jquery I will suggest you making the ajax request simply with jquery methods, so you do not need the XHR detection function:

```
$.get('modules/manage friends/update_friend.php',{ab:a,bc:b,cd:c},function(accdata){

alert(accdata);

document.getElementById('request').value="Request Sent";
 document.getElementById('request').disabled=true;

});
```

Comment: i m just trying it but still the value passed is undefined , dnt know where the problem lies

Comment: another thing I notice is that rate(a,b,c) has 3 parameters and here onclick="rate('$id','$msg_id') you are giving just 2 of them, so c will be undefined

Comment: even after removing it and setting only a and b the vale is undefined

Comment: the error is here `onclick="rate('$id','$msg_id')"` this must be `onclick="rate('<?php echo $id ?>','<?php echo $msg_id ?>')"`